# Access touch history when `touchmove` event is captured

Tags: javascript, multi-touch, gesture, touchmove

I am trying to learn how to use the [`touchmove` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/touchmove) in browser to detect multitouch gestures. When a touchmove event is captured I can obtain a list of **current** touch points. However that is not very useful for detecting gestures. I like to get the history of the touch event. For example I want to get a list of last 10 touch points (if available) that came before each current distinct touch point. I draw the figure below in an attempt to visualize what I am after:

[image]

As I said in this scenario where the user is dragging two seperate fingers on the screen in two different patterns (fingers from different hands), I receive only two touch points inside the `touchmove` event. Is it possible to access history of where each of the two points have been before they got to the point *A* and *B*?

Here is the relevant bit of code for capturing the `touchmove` event:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);

function touchMove(e) {
  console.log("length is: ", e.touches.length);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Please do not suggest third party libraries -- my goal is to learn how to define and detect my own custom true multitouch gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store the previous positions in arrays and iterate over them.

1. Reset the history of them in the `touchstart` event
2. Inside of the `touchmove` event, push the current coordinates as an object onto each array, identified via the `identifier` property of the `Touch` object. You can access the coordinates at the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the `Touch` object available in `event.targetTouches. To only store 10, call`slice(-10)` after you've pushed onto the array.

Comment: if I reset history of them on `touchstart` wouldnt I loose history of all touches? Note that they are indipendant touch points and their start/finish time is independent of other touches. It would be awesome if you could point me to an example, or write a bit of code to demonstrate how this can be done.